# Do Underscore.js and jQuery complement each other?

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I'm just starting to learn JavaScript, and stumbled over [Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) and [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). Underscore looks really cool but I wonder if jQuery does not already provide functions similar to Underscore. So, is it worthwhile to use both?

Comment: The first paragraph on their home page says - "It's the tie to go along with jQuery's tux, and Backbone.js's suspenders."

Comment: yes, but I think what the op is indicating with the word "complement" is that since many of the functions overlap, do the two frameworks really make sense together. For instance, the differences between $.each and _.each are subtle enough to cause anyone to get confused when trying to mix and match between them.

Comment: If you like underscorejs, then you really should be using http://lodash.com/

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Taken from the [underscore](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) site:

> It's the tie to go along with jQuery's tux, and Backbone.js's suspenders.

Underscore is more suited to data manipulation and brings many Ruby methods to JavaScript.  There is some crossover, but not enough to make them mutually exclusive.

Comment: that's a very custom *suit* of frameworks :P

Comment: [Meaning of It's the tie](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45904/meaning-of-its-the-tie-to-go-along-with-xs-tux/45909)

Answer (score 68):

- jQuery will take care of most of your dom manipulation
- backbone.js will help you organize all of your code and give your js application some structure (mvc pattern)
- underscore.js will give you really useful low-level utility.  I would have never needed this library until I really got into js apps (it's also a requirement for backbone.js)

Answer (score 39):

Underscore provides a total of 60 functions for processing data/code. It is agreed that many of the functionalities are present in other libraries like jQuery, Prototype or script.aculo.us. For example, functions like each, map, find, filter or toArray are present in jQuery. These are in Underscore also. This is to make the library independent of jQuery.

**When to use Underscore?**:

Currently, it is widely used with Backbone.js to use MVC architecture for creating a one page Javascript Web app. The most significant ability of underscore.js is the ability of templating (which jQuery can not do). This library has many other useful functions, which are independent of other Javascript libraries.

Find below a list of functions provided by Underscore:

**Collections:**
each,map,reduce,reduceRight,find,filter,reject,all,any,include,invoke,pluck,max,min,sortBy,groupBy,sortedIndex,shuffle,toArray,size

**Array:**
first,initial,last,rest,compact,flatten,without,union,intersection,difference,uniq,zip,indexOf,lastIndexOf,range

**Function:**
bind,bindAll,memoize,delay,defer,throttle,debounce,once,after,wrap,compose

**Object:**
keys,values,functions,extend,defaults,clone,tap,isEqual,isEmpty,isElement,isArray,isArguments,isFunction,isString,isNumber,isBoolean,isDate,isRegExp,isNaN,isNull,isUndefined

**Utitity:**
noConflict,identity,times,mixin,uniqueId,escape,template

Comment: hi Umesh, since _.template is only one of the 60 Underscore functions, is that really enough to make it worthwhile?

Comment: @timpeterson, I understand this. but We are not only using _.template, there are many more functions along with that like bind,bindAll, each,map etc.  We can use many functions as possible.

Comment: but bind, each, map are in jQuery so seems redundant, right?

Comment: Having Reduce (which [jQuery won't add](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/1886)) probably makes it worthwhile all by itself!

Answer (score 9):

If you are concerned about overlap, and do not need things like JQuery AJAX, then you might consider using just the JQuery selector engine, named Sizzle.

http://sizzlejs.com/

Note that this is not for all projects, by using Sizzle and Underscore you will lose some JQuery functionality (like AJAX), you need to consider what you really need for your specific application.

Comment: http://projects.jga.me/jquery-builder/ This tool can help you remove unneeded jQuery code. Also, lodash modules are available on NPM