# How to use throttle from underscore.js

Tags: jquery, underscore.js, throttling

I want to use [throttle from underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#throttle) but I don't know how to implement it in my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        /* Scroll event handler */
        $(window).bind('scroll',function(e){
            parallaxScroll();
        });
    }); 

    /* Scroll the background layers */
    function parallaxScroll(){
        var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
        $('header').css('top',(0+(scrolled*1))+'px');
        $('#balken0').css('top',(-600+(scrolled*1))+'px');
        $('#balken1').css('top',(-1465+(scrolled*1))+'px');
        $('#balken2').css('top',(-2320+(scrolled*1))+'px');
    }
</script>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `var throttled = _.throttle(parallaxScroll, 100);
$(window).scroll(throttled);` ?

Comment: i am very new to jquery :D

Comment: Well, this is very good that you know what `throttle` does.

Comment: ok the code works but i don't want the #balken not to move at all! my problem is that in firefox it works great but safari not!

Comment: @JustKidding see the accepted answer.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907373/do-underscore-js-and-jquery-complement-each-other

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the same result by using a timer. There's no point including an entire library for one function IMO.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var timer;

    /* Scroll event handler */
    $(window).bind('scroll', function(e) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(parallaxScroll, 100);
    });
});
```

This will ensure that the scroll event only fires your parralax function after scrolling has ended, instead of calling it once for every pixel the page is scrolled by.

Comment: this worked! but i already mentioned that it doesn't work for me! i want the #balken not to move at all

Comment: `this worked! but i already mentioned that it doesn't work for me!` What? that doesn't make sense.

Comment: see my comment under my question! ok the code works but i don't want the #balken not to move at all! my problem is that in firefox it works great but safari not!